# c# - StackOverFlowException when mentioning ListBoxt?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get a new form (FormAlbum) to open when I click buttonOpenAlbum and have an item selected in the AlbumListBox.

If I just have this in buttonOpenAlbum_Click:

```
private void buttonOpenAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        FormAlbum MusicForm = new FormAlbum(this);
        MusicForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

The new from opens without error. However, as soon as I mention "AlbumListBox.SelectedItem" (as in the code belowin Form FormMain), I get a "StackOverflowException was unhandled" at:

```
public ListBox AlbumListBox
{
    get
    { // <-This bracket here is where the error highlights
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, only that it must have something to do with AlbumListBox. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Form FormMain:

```
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void buttonAddAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormAlbumAC addAlbumForm = new FormAlbumAC(this);
    addAlbumForm.ShowDialog();
}

private void buttonOpenAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AlbumListBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(AlbumListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        FormAlbum MusicForm = new FormAlbum(this);
        MusicForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select an album from the list to open.");
    }
}

public static class PublicVars
{
    public static List<Album> AlbumList { get; set; }

    static PublicVars()
    {
        AlbumList = new List<Album>(MAX_ALBUMS);
    }
}

public ListBox AlbumListBox
{
    get
    {
        return AlbumListBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: The getter of AlbumListBox return itself, this cause the exception. Change the public property name and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your property implementation:

```
public ListBox AlbumListBox
{
    get
    {
        return AlbumListBox;
    }
}
```

It's just calling itself, recursively. It may be easier to see that if we convert it to a method:

```
public ListBox GetAlbumListBox()
{
    return GetAlbumListBox();
}
```

That's why you've got an overflow. It's not clear what you *meant* it to do... where did you expect the value to come from? You probably need a variable to back the property. What did you expect to *set* the value returned?

I'd also *strongly* discourage the design of the `PublicVars` class. Aside from the naming, you're basically using global variables - not a good idea. Work out which classes need access to the data, and how to get that data to them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm still new to using c#, so I don't know what the correct implementation is. Could you give me an example of what it should say instead?

Comment: @user2251281: No, because we don't know what you're *trying* to do. What value do you want to be returned?

Comment: I'm trying to return the selected item in the list box, or in this particular instance, just return whether an item is selected. I'm not sure how to refer to AlbumListBox on FormMain. On a separate form I refer to it "formMain.AlbumsListBox" and it seemed to work with the code I had put together, so although I didn't have an understanding of what was going on, I just left it as was because it was working.

Comment: In a separate form (FormAlbumAC) in "private void buttonSave_Click" I had the line "formMain.ListAlbums(formMain.AlbumsListBox.Items);". Before I created "public ListBox AlbumListBox { get { return AlbumListBox; } }" in FromMain, it didn't work. And then after it did and changing it stopped it working, so I left it alone, not understanding how it was working.

Comment: So now I guess my question is "How do I refer to AlbumsListBox in FormMain, while also being able to refer to it in FormAlbumAC?". As I said in an earlier comment, I'm new to using c#, so I'm still learning how to link things together, especially across multiple forms.

Comment: Well now the other form works without that code. I'm just going to delete "public ListBox AlbumListBox" and try again without code that makes no sense. Sorry about that, and thank you for the advise.